# Laravel job query Asynchronous / Synchronous?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

Is Laravel job queue is Asynchronous?

I want to execute a list of processes in **Synchronous** manner

Say i have three processes in the job queue

1. **Process-1**
2. **Process-2**
3. **Process-3**

I want to execute **process-2** only after successful execution of **process-1** or after 3 failed attempts for **process-1** so on ...

If the queues are Synchronous this isn't a problem, am i right?

If the queues are Asynchronous, Then what is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Job Chaining, which is described as:

> Job chaining allows you to specify a list of queued jobs that should
>   be run in sequence. If one job in the sequence fails, the rest of the
>   jobs will not be run.

Check out the documentation at: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#job-chaining